# Valuechangelistener on <p:selectOneMenu> works but an Exception is being thrown. Why?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I'm using Primefaces 3.3.1 and have a `<p:selectOneMenu>` where I'm selecting a new value. When selecting a new value a valueChangeListener-method is being called where the value is being processed. Like this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="signature-menu" value="#{objectBuffertBean.loggedInSignature}" effect="fold" style="width: 125px;">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="signature-menu" 
                listener="#{loginBean.changeSignature()}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{signaturesBean.signatures}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

LoginBean.java:

```
public void changeSignature(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    if (e.getNewValue() != null) {
        try {
            WebDB db = new WebDB();

            SessionHandler.getInstance().
                    getCurrentObjectBuffert().setSignature(
                    db.getSignatureBySignatureFromWebDb(
                                           (String) e.getNewValue()
                    ));
        } catch (DatabaseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But, the strange thing is that when I'm selecting a new value I get this exception:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method changeSignature not found
```

And it works! the method is being called somehow and the new value is being processed!!
Is there anyone who have had the same strange complication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing `valueChangeListener` attribute of `UIInput` with `listener` attribute of `<p:ajax>`/`<f:ajax>`. The `ValueChangeEvent` argument is only supported on the method behind `valueChangeListener` attribute. The method behind the `listener` attribute of `<p:ajax>`/`<f:ajax>` must take `AjaxBehaviorEvent` argument (or just nothing).

So

```
 public void changeSignature(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
     if (loggedInSignature != null) {
         // ...
     }
 }
```

or

```
 public void changeSignature() {
     if (loggedInSignature != null) {
         // ...
     }
 }
```

Note that the submitted value is already set on the property behind the `UIInput` component's `value` attribute, so there's no need to get it by the event somehow. This is because this runs during invoke action phase instead of the validations phase like the `valueChangeListener`. Also, the `valueChangeListener` should technically **only** be used when you intend to have *both* the old and the new value in the method.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `event="change"` attribute of `<p:ajax>` is already the default. You can just omit it. Also those method parentheses from the `listener` attribute should preferably be omitted as it adds no value. Just use `listener="#{loginBean.changeSignature}"`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your detailed response. I got what i needed :)